# How do I open an unrecognized version .sln file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to web development, and have been having a considerable amount of trouble trying to get my asp.net project running using Visual Studio 2010. Please help.

I am working on a web development project that references a database using SQL 2008 R2. I was having problems with turning on/off features on my computer, the asp.net and .net features, etc. I would get an error that read "An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed." I tried several solutions to fix this, and none worked. I ended up using a cleanup tool I found online, it said use as a last resort, which is where I was at.

Here is the link: 
http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog_Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip

This ended up fixing my problems with the features, but then I was not able to use Visual Studio 2010. I got an error "Cannot create the window". To fix this I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio 2010. Now I am again running into the problem where I cannot turn on the asp.net and .net features with the same error as before.

Now that is not my only problem, I cannot open my project solution file. It is giving me 2 errors when i open the .sln file "The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of the application and cannot be opened." and  "The system cannot find the file specified." in that order. The .sln file says it is an unrecognized version.

I have previously worked on this project using Visual Studio 2010, before I tried to fix the problems with the features. I can still open other .sln files that I worked on before, but they do not reference outside sources. I have tried opening the .sln file in notepad and changing the version from 12.00 to 11.00 (on line 1) and changing #Visual Studio 2012 to #Visual Studio 2010 (on line 2). I need to work on this project as soon as possible. Any help would be great.

Will someone help me identify the problem?
How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to use an existing solution. A solution file just references a bunch of projects and groups them together.

I would suggest you create a new blank solution and then add all of your existing projects into that one, assuming you don't have a similar issue with adding in the projects as well.

Comment: I have created a new .sln file and moved all of the files(as far as I can see) into the new folder. I am still having problems opening a bunch of .cs files. The error says "There was a problem sending the command to the program." Any ideas of the next step I should take? Is there a way for me to fix and use the old .sln file ?

Comment: By adding them to the new folder, do you mean you dragged them onto the new solution in Visual Studio?

You could also check your old solution file by opening it in notepad (or an xml reader) and try to determine which project file(s) it can't open. Maybe make a backup of it, then remove the projects one by one until you can find the culprit.

Comment: Right, I just copied and pasted them into the new directory that was created when I made the new solution. I don't want to delete anything at this point.. When I open the project in Visual Studio the folder icons are all hollow, although I can still open them.